# CoffeeScript loop through methods

Tags: javascript, loops, methods, coffeescript

I have an object literal that I'm using to group methods. I'd like to be able to call a whole group  of methods easily, like so:

```
group =
  methodA: (str) ->
    console.log str + "from method A"

  methodB: (str) ->
    console.log str + "from method B"

for method in group
  method "hello"

# should log to console:
# "hello from method A"
# "hello from method B"
```

When I try this it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing / how should you go about looping through a group of methods like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for ... in` compiles down to a `for` loop that assumes you are looping over an array - use `for own ... of` instead:

```
group =
  methodA: (str) ->
    console.log str + "from method A"

  methodB: (str) ->
    console.log str + "from method B"

for own method of group
  group[method] "hello"
```

Comment: Getting `TypeError: method is not a function`. If I just do `console.log method` in the for loop it prints `methodA, methodB`

Comment: Mea culpa @Andrew - I've fixed it (`for ... of` enumerates **keys** not values).

Comment: Ah, I get it. I didn't realize you could call a method like you were accessing a hash property, but of course that's all it is, so why not! Thanks!